# Find duplicate elements in a list in Python using index based location search

Tags: javascript, python, duplicates

Following is a Javascript based code which can find whether in an array there are duplicate elements present or not.

```
function hd(Ar)
{
    let ev = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < Ar.length; i++)
    {
        if(ev[Ar[i]] === 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            ev[Ar[i]] = 1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(hd([1,2,3,4,5,1]))
```

I am trying to create a Python equivalent code for the same. Here is what I tried using dictionaries, but it is generating the Key error as initially, the dictionary is empty.

```
def find_dupes(A):
  n = len(A)
  D = {}
  for i in A:
    if D[i] == 1:
      return True
    else:
      D[i] = 1
  return False

print(find_dupes([3,5,4])) # Supposed to return False
print(find_dupes([3,5,4,5])) # Supposed to return True
```

I am looking for any Python equivalent code to achieve the same results as I am getting using Javascript. The algorithm should proceed in such a way that it puts the value to the index, which is the same as its value.

Comment: Test if D is empty: `if i in D and D[i] == 1:`

Comment: @MilanLakhani Well that would defeat the point of an "index based location search".

Comment: You could also use a defaultdict

Comment: @MilanLakhani Maybe safer: `def find_dupes(A): return len(A) != len(set(A))`

Comment: @MilanLakhani That doesn't work.

Comment: These two approaches are not the same, since a JS object would coerce its keys to strings, while a Python dictionary would compute the hash values. `hd([2, '2']) // JS: true` / `find_dupes([2, '2']) # Python: false`

Comment: @InSync It looks like the input consists of only numbers

Comment: @pink Even if that's the case, OP is not entirely safe: `hd([12e34, '1.2e+35']) // true`. My point is that every language have unexpected quirks and advantages of its own and that translating a program might not be a good idea.

Comment: Transpilation from JS to Python seems very simple to do in this case, no?

Comment: @InSync `"1.2e+35"` is not a number, and we should only be concerned about the Python

Comment: That example is off, sure, but my point still stands. I'm just saying that the function could be more Pythonic by using, say, a set, as suggested by mplungjan.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
def find_dupes(A):
    n = len(A)
    D = {}
    for i in A:
        if D.get(i) == 1:
            return True
        else:
            D[i] = 1
    return False

print(find_dupes([3,5,4])) # Supposed to return False
print(find_dupes([3,5,4,5])) # Supposed to return True
```